# delete() does not work sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am setting up an account deactivation activity in my app but the `user.delete()` method does not work sometimes...

The fact that it works sometimes and does not some other time is really confusing... If it's a logic error it should not work all of the time right?

this is the code that I have

```
deactivateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        deletePosts();
        deleteComments();
        deleteLikes();
        deleteUser();
        user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                Toast.makeText(DeactivateAccount.this, "You account has been deactivated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent (DeactivateAccount.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);

            }

        });


    }
```

There is no error so I don't know how to debug this as well... but the deletePosts(), deleteComments(), deleteLikes(), and deleteUser() methods all work perfectly... but it leaves the user undeleted in the authentication tab... their e-mail is still there.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try checking if the completed Task isSuccessful(), and if not, log getException(). https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#isSuccessful()

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your intent and calling your startActivity() in

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() onAuthSChanged()
```

method.

```
    // This listener will be called when there is change in FireBase user session
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(DeactivateAccount.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
```